# Symfony - Doctrine nested forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

At the moment I am creating a form with questions and answers which are saved in separated database tables. The question forms has a collection type which include the answer form.

So my Question form has this inside the form builder:

```
 ->add('Question', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => AnswerForm::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
])
```

I have a question service were I clone the current question and clone it to another record in order to keep tracking on the changes. But the clone of object question does not save a extra record in the answer. There is a doctrine relation between question to answer  OneToMany.

How can i make this also possible to save the answer as new record if the answer is changed.

At the moment i have two methods which i call Entity Manager persist and flush to edit the the current object and save the new one in the question table. I want to implement the same logic into my answer table but without success so far.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You want to have the answers get cloned when you clone the question? It is not possible to have that using clone question because the question ID needs to exist before any answers can get linked to them...

Comment: Hi @JoeYahchouchi i want to keep revisions of the answers like i do in the questions. So i can track the changed questions and answers. But since i have no control about the nested forms its hard to monitor this.